# Stop a specific cron job using whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I'm using the `whenever` gem and got it working. Lets say, I have 3 schedule on my `schedule.rb`

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  puts "cron 1"
end

every :hour do
  puts "cron 2"
end

every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do
  puts "cron 3"
end
```

I guess the cron runs and lets me know about it. How can I stop a specific job (eg "cron 2") ?, I know I can stop that by run `whenever -c` but I don't want to stop another job (cron 1 & 3), Also don't want to manual edit crontab file.

Answer (score 0):

[`Cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a time-based job scheduler running as a daemon process in Unix environment. People use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run **periodically** at fixed **times, dates, or intervals**. [`Whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is a Ruby gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and deploying cron jobs.

You can't use it like you want(skip a specific job) without manual edit crontab file.

Comment: I can't use `whenever` like I want, but doesn't mean I should manual edit crontab file, right? maybe, I try to build a method from scratch using ruby to edit a crontab, also build a method for define each job (or custom `whenever` gem). Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @itx build  a method to edit crontab its a bad decision. I suggest you add a logic to ruby code.

Comment: I have read some code of `whenever` gem and I found an option for identification on [this line](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/command_line.rb#L14) , Is that to define every job to each file for identification of specific job?, so I can stop a specific job by run `whenever --clear-crontab [some_identifier_name]`

Comment: It's not a _stop job_ action, it is editing a crontab file. If job already running you can't stop it by cleaning crontab file.

Comment: by already running, I mean ruby code, which has been launched by  cron.

Comment: That's it, you've explanation on your answer "you can only manual edit crontab file" for "stop a specific job", stop a specific job (on my question) mean remove a schedule from crontab not a `stop job` action, and I found  `whenever` have an option to identification every job, and can stop/clear (edit crontab) it by running with `whenever --clear-crontab [some_identifier_name]`